# Single Page Application or Multi-page Application?

Tags: django, mongodb, backbone.js, single-page-application

I am working on a web application project. This web application will have many users, and each user will be able to upload images to the website. Then I will write an android application to access those images. This is the description of my project.

Should I go with single page application such as backbone.js or should i go with a multi-page application approach such as Django? For the database stuff, I was thinking of going with Mongodb for now. Any advice on that is very appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: Whatever you are comfortable for. Those two approaches have completely different prerequisites, ways of achieving roughly the same goals, and, most important, the language majority of code is written (python for multipage, javascript for single page). So, the question is a bit unanswerable, since we can't estimate your proficiency in any of the mentioned techniques. :) Thus, voting to close (well, to "put on hold") as non-constructive (I mean, we can't answer that). Both approaches will do, the question is which you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I see, thanks btw. I might go with Django then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An SPA (single page app) has nothing to do with going with Django or Backbone. You can write an SPA while using Django. BUT you can also use Backbone along with Django. For more on this, read these posts:

1. http://sidazad.tumblr.com/post/52201957429/web-2-0-the-switch-to-client-javascript-frameworks
2. http://sidazad.tumblr.com/post/52591790157/the-search-for-the-perfect-software-stack-part-1

**To answer your question**, I'd say use Backbone + Django and go with a Single Page App. That's where the web is moving. By using Backbone as well as Django you will get the advantages that Django provides on the server side while getting the great client side code organization and plumbing for a SPA from Backbone.

There are ways in which you can write your django templates so they are reusable on the client side. Look at this project in my GitHub for help with this on which I will be writing a post soon:

https://github.com/sidazad/django-backbone-stack-1